# default value for multiple select in form antd 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm unable to set default value for multi select inside form.

**Use Case:**
I have created a react component that renders a select with some default props that I need in every form.
Now I want to set default value for that select from the `defaultValue` prop of select instead of passing `initialValues` to every form.

My react component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Select } from 'antd';

class FormSelect extends Component {
  render() {
    const {name, label, rules, onSelect, disabled, options, mode} = this.props;

    let defaultValue;
    if (mode === 'tags' || mode === 'multiple'){
      defaultValue = [];
    }

    return (
      <Form.Item
        hasFeedback
        name={name}
        label={label}
        rules={rules}
      >
        <Select
          showSearch
          mode={mode}
          tokenSeparators={[',']}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          onSelect={onSelect}
          disabled={disabled}
        >
          {
            options.map((op) => (
              <Select.Option key={op.value} value={op.value} label={op.label}>
                {op.label}
              </Select.Option>
            ))
          }
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
    );
  }
}
export default FormSelect;
```

The problem is when I set the `defaultValue` prop of select the value is shown in UI but when the form is submitted the defaultValue is ignored and value of select field remains `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`Form.Item` now supports `initialValue` prop in version 4.2.2 which can be used to set default value.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you need to do something like this in the callback of your `options.map()`:

```
<Select.Option
  selected={op.value === this.props.defaultValue ? true : false}
  key={op.value}
  value={op.value}
  label={op.label}>
    {op.label}
</Select.Option>
```

Explanation: If `op.value` of an option is equal to the `defaultValue` passed as props, that option will be selected by default.

React is smart enough to know whether to add `selected` attribute to a particular option or not based upon its value being `true` or `false`.

Comment: No, You didn't got the question right.
For e.g. if no item is selected the value of FormSelect should give an empty array but the actual default value in antd for select is `undefined`. So how can you handle this case.
For this you need to set some default value.

Comment: Also, antd `Select.Option` doesn't provide any `selected` prop

Comment: Does passing a `defaultValue` prop in `<Select />` solves your problem? Try passing an empty array to it. https://ant.design/components/select/#Select-props

Comment: Your `defaultValue` is being set based upon the value of `mode`. Try assigning it as an empty array from the starting and not conditionally.

Comment: setting defaultValue as empty array doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can't you check for the value of `Select`? If it's `undefined`, explicitly reassign it to an empty array. I haven't used antd, so don't know the exacts.

Comment: Same problem here ! Any solution ?